# Python is adding extra newline to the output

Tags: python

The input file: `a.txt`

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
```

The python code:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

The problem:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbb

cccccccccccc
```

as you can see the output has extra line between each item.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`print` appends a newline, and the input lines already end with a newline.

A standard solution is to output the input lines verbatim:

```
import sys

with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**PS**: For Python 3 (or Python 2 with the print function), abarnert's `print(…, end='')` solution is the simplest one.

Comment: The OP is clearly using Python 2, and I'm not sure suggesting `print_function` for 2.x users is always a good idea. And using `print`'s magic soft space is probably a bad idea if you don't first learn what it means and how it works. Which means your explicit `write` may be the best answer (which is why I upvoted your answer, and think the OP was right to accept it).

Answer (score 11):

As the other answers explain, each line has a newline; when you `print` a bare string, it adds a line at the end. There are two ways around this; everything else is a variation on the same two ideas.

---

First, you can strip the newlines as you read them:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip()
```

This will strip any other trailing whitespace, like spaces or tabs, as well as the newline. Usually you don't care about this. If you do, you probably want to use universal newline mode, and strip off the newlines:

```
with open("a.txt", "rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip('\n')
```

However, if you know the text file will be, say, a Windows-newline file, or a native-to-whichever-platform-I'm-running-on-right-now-newline file, you can strip the appropriate endings explicitly:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip('\r\n')

with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip(os.linesep)
```

---

The other way to do it is to leave the original newline, and just avoid printing an extra one. While you can do this by writing to `sys.stdout` with `sys.stdout.write(line)`, you can also do it from `print` itself.

If you just add a comma to the end of the `print` statement, instead of printing a newline, it adds a "smart space". [Exactly what that means](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) is a bit tricky, but the idea is supposed to be that it adds a space when it should, and nothing when it shouldn't. Like most DWIM algorithms, it doesn't always get things right—but in this case, it does:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

Of course we're now assuming that the file's newlines match your terminal's—if you try this with, say, classic Mac files on a Unix terminal, you'll end up with each line printing over the last one. Again, you can get around that by using universal newlines.

Anyway, you can avoid the DWIM magic of smart space by using the print function instead of the print statement. In Python 2.x, you get this by using a `__future__` declaration:

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```

Or you can use a third-party wrapper library like `six`, if you prefer.

Comment: stripping `\r` is useless because you have opened the file in text mode: the `\r` char is removed _before_ you have to strip it. Useful only with python 2 and binary mode for text files (not compatible with python 3)

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that each line as a newline at the end, and `print` statement in python also adds a newline.  You can strip the newlines:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: `strip()` removes leading white spaces too, so this solution fails to correctly print the input file when it contains lines that start with spaces. You actually want `rstrip()`. Even `rstrip()` is not so good: it removes newlines (which is good), but also trailing spaces, which modifies the lines of the input file in some possible unwanted way, so even an `rstrip()` version does not fully do what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the `splitlines()` function, it strips automatically:

```
f = open('a.txt').read()
for l in f.splitlines():
    print l
```

Comment: While this correctly handles the various newline convention of multiple operating systems, in both Python 2 and Python 3 this solution can take a lot of memory: not only is the whole file read in memory, but a copy is made through the list of its lines. So, this is a method that works, but only for files that are not too large. Note that memory would ultimately be freed if this solution used a `with`, like in some other answers.

Comment: @EOL: The `with` won't affect freeing memory. Whether you close the file or not, the giant `f` string is live for exactly the same amount of time either way. (Of course it's still a good idea to not leak file handles. It's just not relevant to GC'ing `f`, or `f.splitlines`.)

Comment: @abarnert: You're right. I'm not sure why I wrote that memory would be freed with `with` (the involved memory amount is indeed negligible).

Answer (score 0):

It is not adding a newline, but each scanned line from your file has a trailing one.

Try:

```
with open ("a.txt") as f:
    for line in (x.rstrip ('\n') for x in f):
        print line
```

Comment: This fails on Windows (or Mac OS before OS X), because the newline character is not `\n`.

Comment: This also fails if the file a.txt does not exist.

Comment: @EOL AFAIK, and I might be wrong, files opened in text-mode in python have all their line-endings implicitely converted to '\n'.

Comment: You can simply `for line in f: print(line.rstrip())`, or you can use [`os.linesep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) if you want to be specific.

Comment: Strange enough, I just ran it on Windows7 and it worked as expected. Without 'rU', the exact code as posted.

Comment: This is probably because the `\r` character kept by your `rstrip()` has no visible effect here (I guess that it puts the cursor back to the beginning of the line). I guess that you can see the difference between the two file opening modes by printing `repr(line[-1])`: I expect it to be `\r`, in the default mode under Windows (and the last non-newline character of the line in universal newline mode).

Comment: Printing out [ord (x) for x in line] shows no \r character at all.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: In my experience, code that works on multiple platforms with no much effort is a much better way of coding a given task, because it uses tools that are designed to correctly perform the task at hand, as opposed to platform-specific code that mostly hacks a partial solution that misses some important concepts (like the fact that different OSes use different newline conventions).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It looks like your input file is not a Windows text file. A Windows text file should has `\r\n` at the end of each line. The documentation is quite explicit about `\r\n` being kept as is in default mode (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).