# python file concatenation and combining files

Tags: python, string, concatenation

My main problem is this:

I have a set of files, and I am concatenating them this way in python:

```
   sys.stdout=open("out.dat","w")
filenames = ['bla.txt', 'bla.txt', 'bla.txt']
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
with open('out.dat') as f:
    print "".join(line.strip() for line in f)  
sys.stdout.close()
```

The bla.txt file looks like

> aaa

and the intention is to make it look like

> aaaaaaaaa

(3 times the same string, not on a new line each time...)

for some reason what I do produces an output that looks like

> aaaaaa
>
> a

I am not sure why this is happening and if there is a simpler/more elegant  solution.

More second problem is that eventually, my plan is to have  a number of different  files (letter triplets for example) that I could concatenate in all possible combinations: aaabbbccc,aaacccbbb, ...,etc

Any guidance appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Are you sure there aren't some \n or space or tabs in the bla.txt. The output I get in `out.dat` is exactly what you described it should be.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first line: `sys.stdout=open("out.dat","w")`?

Comment: You could try doing `outfile.write(infile.read(),)`

Comment: Please note that `print` appends a newline. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028504/python-is-adding-extra-newline-to-the-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nihey Takizawa post almost answers why you've got this error. First, let's see what is going on on each step of the program execution.

```
sys.stdout=open("out.dat","w")
```

This is pretty important. Because you replace stdout with file handler to "out.dat", every internal function or statement that use it will write to "out.dat" from now on.

```
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

After this block, content of the file "out.dat" is:

```
aaa
aaa 
aaa
```

...or in other words: `aaa\naaa\naaa\n` where `\n` is single character standing for newline. Number of chars: 12 (9 times `a` and 3 times newline `\n`).

```
with open('out.dat') as f:
    print "".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```

Here is important thing. Remember, that because in step 1 you've changed sys.stdout to "out.dat" internal function `print` writes output to "out.dat".

You strip each line and join them, so you write "aaaaaaaaa" to "out.dat".

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
a  a  a \n  a  a  a \n  a  a  a \n  # this is content of the file before print
a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a \n       # that you write, 9 a chars + \n
                                   # which is added by print function by default
```

Note, that you've replaced 10 out of 12 characters and close the file, so 11 and 12 chars would remain the same. Result is your output.

Solution? **NEVER** mess with things like by changing sys.stdout file handler unless you know what you're doing.

**EDIT:** How to fix your code. 
I thought that Nihey Takizawa nicely explained how to fix your code, but it's actually not completely correct as I see. Here's solution:

```
filenames = ['bla.txt', 'bla.txt', 'bla.txt']
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read().strip())
```

Now your `out.dat` file contains `aaaaaaaaa` string only without newlines.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but you are not giving any suggestions on how to just make the output into a single line instead of being separated by /n?

Comment: Thank you. That works beautifully, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

There are some confusing things about your code, I'll leave some comments on the respective places:

```
# Not sure what is reason for this
sys.stdout=open("out.dat","w")

filenames = ['bla.txt', 'bla.txt', 'bla.txt']

# This does what you need
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

# Here, you open `out.dat` and rewrites it content back into it - 
# because you made `sys.stdout = open("out.dat", "w")` above.
# All these lines could be removed (along with `sys.stdout` assignment above)
with open('out.dat') as f:
    print "".join(line.strip() for line in f)  
sys.stdout.close()
```

The most minimalistic approach I could think of:

```
# Open output
with open('out.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    # Iterate over each input
    for infilename in ['bla.txt'] * 3:
        # Open each input and write it to output
        with open(infilename) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

As for your error, it should not be happening, could you confirm that the content of `bla.txt` is exactly `aaa`?