# Python3 sys.stdout.write delete last line

Tags: python

ip.txt

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.10
127.0.0.15
```

Code

```
user@linux:~$ cat script01.py 
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
user@linux:~$
```

Output

```
user@linux:~$ python script01.py 
127.0.0.1

127.0.0.10

127.0.0.15
user@linux:~$
```

One of the solution provided to remove additional new line was to use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`

[Python is adding extra newline to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028504/python-is-adding-extra-newline-to-the-output)

New code with `sys.stdout.write`

```
user@linux:~$ cat script02.py 
import sys

with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # print(line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
user@linux:~$
```

However, `sys.stdout.write` delete the last line.

```
user@linux:~$ python script02.py 
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.10
127.0.0.15user@linux:~$
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [strip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) to remove the line break:

```
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip("\r\n"))
```

The argument `"\r\n"` makes the function to only delete all newlines and carriage returns at the beginnig and end of the line. Without that argument it would also delete spaces and tabs at the beginning and end what you might not want.

Comment: Thanks @Sadap. `print(line.strip())` also produce similar output

Comment: Yes, the output is similar as long as you don't have spaces or tabs at the beginning or at the end

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```